# No given name or surname claim when using Azure Active Directory OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are authenticating our MVC application using Azure Active Directory but the only information we get back in our ClaimsPrincipal is the Name and Group Memberships.

We need access to the users given name and last name as well.  Any pointers on how we can resolve this?

Comment: Hi Shane, did you have any progress figuring this out? I'm trying this out now and also do not get these (given name and surname) claims coming through.

Answer (score 3):

OpenID Connect introduces an id_token (This is a JWT).

Looking at the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/), the id_token contains some claims that could match :

- given_name: Provides the first or "given" name of the user, as set on the Azure AD user object.
- family_name: Provides the last name, surname, or family name of the user as defined in the Azure AD user object.
- unique_name: Provides a human readable value that identifies the subject of the token. This value is not guaranteed to be unique within a tenant and is designed to be used only for display purposes.

So in your controller you can access these claims like that:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
...
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var lastName = identity.Claims.First(
    c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname").Value;
var firstName = identity.Claims.First(
    c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname").Value;
var displayName = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "name").Value;
```

These claims correspond to the First Name, Last Name and Display Name in your Azure AD :

[image: Azure AD Basic User Information]

Comment: That's the problem.  We do not see those claims at all and based off the documentation we are using OpenID v2.0.  We've also had infrastructure verify that those details are in Azure AD.  That said what we are seeing is on our local machines and when I think about it I'm not sure how the auth stuff is working in there since the ReplyURL is wrong.  I'll look at that and update the question.

Comment: Sure, I used the default template from VS 2015 with Azure AD authentication when you create a new project.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille did you have any progress figuring this out? I'm trying this out now and also do not get these (given name and surname) claims coming through.

Comment: @MatthewBoniface, can you check these claims exists in you azure ad / identity provider ?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I've checked in our Azure B2C user flow configuration that it has these Application claims selected - but they just don't come through with the token. Can't see any other configurations in B2C that would affect this.

Comment: Can you check waht are the returned claims? => the names may be different... it could be given_name, family_name, unique_name or name depends if it is oauth2 or openidconnect protocol. also can you see the properties populated in the user details in azure portal ?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply. So it seems it does work with our sign up flow - so just don't know why it doesn't work for sign in flow. But you were right that the claim Types were different to what I expected, needed to use "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" and "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname". This will do for now,  but still scratching my head as to why it does not work for the sign in flow.

Comment: ARe you checking id_token /and/or access_token ??

Comment: I had a similar issue. I had to add the optional claim for the first and last names to the ID token since that was the only token I was using. Then the user had to log out and log back in to get the info added to the ID token.

Comment: for me adding the `profile` scope to the request helped.